# Detect Android version in .htaccess

Tags: android, apache, .htaccess

How can I detect the version of Android devices in an htaccess file? Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory_for_android_1_x/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android1.x" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory_for_android_1_x/ [L,R=302]
```

I need to hit 1.x, 2.x, 3.x and 4.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, not with any sort of reliability - user agent sniffing is complicated and fraught with peril, and if you're doing it all it shouldn't be via `.htaccess`.

You'll be a lot better off using something like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect supported **features** and CSS @media queries to and adjust your site's behaviour accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is a simple solution which is reliable enough.
Let's assume you're going to redirect all androids <4 to some other directory:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Android 1" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Android 2" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "Android 3" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directory_for_older_androids/ [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 0):

http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ has the .htaccess one (Apache)

Download it and trimm it down to the code you want.